# Cannot import numpy while using pybind11

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, pybind11

The statement "import numpy" in my python3 file generates error when I try to embed this file in C++ using pybind11. Except "import numpy" and "import tensorflow" Other statements (importing system libraries) in the following python file can successfully be executed

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np    

import sys
print('sys.version: ', sys.version)    
import os
print('os.getcwd: ', os.getcwd())    
import platform
print('platform: ', platform.platform())    
import time
print("Python time: ", time.time());

def create_vector(a,b):
    my_list = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ]
    return my_list
```

I get the following Error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can successfully import and use numpy from a standalone python file or shell (see the following)

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(np.__version__)
1.18.5
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to know what error is generated.

Comment: Compare the values of `sys.path` between two interpreters.

Comment: sys.path return the same paths.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This includes not only buildable runnable source code and complete build instructions, but also any input, expected output, and actual output that you observe, error messages and all. "It generates error" is not a useful piece of information.

Comment: @Fisa was this ever resolved? I'm running into the same issue. I can import the `sys` module just fine, but not `numpy`

Comment: Yes. I posted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Write pyfile.py with the code mentioned in question.
Write main.cpp with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pybind11/embed.h"
namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    auto py_module = py::module::import("pyfile");
}
```

Write CMakeLists.txt with the following code

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
project(project) # project name
include_directories (/usr/include/python3.6m)# set accordingly
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
add_executable(project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (project pybind11::embed)# keep bybind11 dir along with main.cpp
```

properly link pyfile or keep it in build directory.
delete CMakeCache.txt before building (cmake .. and make)

Comment: Why do I need an interpreter when I am not executing any code?